# How to assign specific colors to data items in a doughnut chart in Angular Chart?

Tags: angularjs, charts, colors, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using [Angular Chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) and I have a [doughnut chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#doughnut-chart). I want to have specific colors for my data.

**For example:**

```
$scope.labels = ["Oranges", "Bananas", "Avocados"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
$scope.colors = [
    "#ff9900", // oranges are orange :)
    "ffff00",  // bananas are yellow 
    "1E824C"]; // avocados are green
```

Now, I can only change the global colors, but this doesn't guarantee me that the oranges are going to be orange, the bananas yellow and the avocados green. Moreover, I have more than one doughnut chart where the same series are used and they have to be with the same colors - e.g. the bananas are always yellow.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-colours="colors">
</canvas>
```

You are also missing `#` in color codes:

So this should be :

```
$scope.colors = [
    "#1E824C", // oranges are orange :)
    "#1E824C",  // bananas are yellow 
    "#1E824C"];
```

Comment: can you bring up a plunk of current situation?

Comment: @Yulian : Working fine at my end. jsbin.com/dobuzusene/edit?html,js,output

Comment: omg, it seems like the reason is that I've pasted the colors without the #, as you've mentioned. I will test it again and give feedback :)